# How to generate runnable jar file without main class in a selenium test framework?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created a selenium testing framework using Maven, TestNG. I can run testng tests xml file. But unable find the proper steps for creating the runnable jar file without the main class.

Comment: Without main method it is not possible to create runnable jar file.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse supports the creation of different JAR file types.

You want to create a "runnable" JAR. But in order to run ... a JAR file you needs a main() method.

Note: simply export as "ordinary" JAR. See the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm) for further reading; and follow the instructions for "Creating a New JAR File".

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is impossible to create an executable jar without a main method. Execution of the jar is totally based on the presence of the main method. If you don't want to use the main method than you can create a batch file having the desired commands for the execution of your test suits.
  Additionally, make sure your tests are written with proper testNG annotations so that they can be executed on a single click of the executable batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually **there is** a [main method](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java#L1293) in the [testng.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng) already therefore you should be able to run your tests like:

```
java -cp "/path/to/test.jar;/path/to/test/dependencies/*" org.testng.TestNG /path/to/your/testng.xml
```

You can also come up with your own entry point by generating a helper class like:

```
package com.example;

import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setTestClasses(new Class[]{TestClass.class}); // replace TestClass with your actual class where your test methods live
        testNG.run();
    }
}
```

Which can be build into an executable

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Main-Class>com.example.TestRunner</Main-Class>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

More information:

- [TestNG](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/TestNG)
- [Running TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng)